# How to take random samples from data set with increasing size in R?

Tags: r, plot, sampling

I am using R (new to the program) and tasked with taking random samples from an existing data set (n=1412), but with increasing size (i.e. n=10....n=1000) and plotting the relationship between (x) increasing sample sizes and (y) the proportion of the sum of two variables (see below for details).

The two variables I am interested are coded [0 "No", 1 "Yes"]. I am  interested in the proportion of who said "Yes" from the total sample size (i.e. When N=20, Y= 5/20 or 0.25).

I know how to make a random sample for whatever single size and plot the relationship (see code below). What I do not know how to do, is make multiple samples of different sizes (n=10:1000) and then plot them on the x-axis with their corresponding proportion on the y-axis.

```
datasubset1<-data[sample(nrow(data), 100, replace= FALSE), ]
Vars1<-data$pwd
Vars2<-data$sendwd

y<-(sum(data$pwd + data$sendwd)/100)

x<-100

plot(x,y,col="red", type= "p", main = "Sample Size Effects on Proportion", ylab = "Proportion", xlab= "Sample Size")
```

When I input the code, I obviously get 1 data point (0.46) for when the sample size is 100; this I can plot easily.

However, I need to plot sample sizes from n=10 to n=1000 (x) and the proportion of Vars1+Vars2/n (y).

Comment: It looks like you want to replace `100` in your first and fourth line with `x`. You might want to turn your current code into a "function" also, although this might not be necessary. Then you could use a "for loop" `for(x in 10:1000){` or something from the "apply" family, e.g. `lapply(10:1000, function(x){`. My favorite way to do this sort of thing is `purrr::map_dfr(10:1000, function(x){`

Comment: Something like `library(tidyverse)`

`my_df<-map_dfr(10:100, function(x){`
`    datasubset1<-data[sample(nrow(data), x, replace= FALSE), ]`
`    #Vars1<-data$pwd`
`    #Vars2<-data$sendwd`
`    y<-(sum(datasubset1$pwd + ` `datasubset1$sendwd)/100)`return(data.frame(x=x, y=y))`
`})`



`plot(my_df$x,my_df$y,col="red", type= "p", main = "Sample Size Effects on Proportion", ylab = "Proportion", xlab= "Sample Size")`.      To be reproducible, it's great to include sample data, also :-)

Comment: Sorry, the code above is supposed to be all code from `library` to `"Size")`. I was too slow to edit in the comment box.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your input it was really helpful! I finally got it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to create some data:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1412
dat <- data.frame(pwd=rbinom(n, 1, .25), sendwd=rbinom(n, 1, .25))
```

`dat` is your data set. We are generating random 1's and 0's with a probability of .25 for 1's. You are only interested in two columns so if your real data has more than two columns, just extract the two you need. Now the steps to get a sample are the ones you show above:

```
smpl <- sample.int(n, 10)
dat.s10 <- dat[smpl, ]
sum(dat.s10)/10
```

Now we create a vector of sample sizes and nest the above commands to use `sapply()`:

```
size <- c(10, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000)
results <- sapply(size, function(x) sum(dat[sample.int(n, x), ])/x)
plot(size, results, type="l")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried this method out as well and it worked the same way (and it looks elegant as well).